# How to convert amplitude (V) to dB (V^2/Hz or V/sqrt(Hz) or V?)

Tags: dsp, fft, units, psd

I took the FFT of a signal and am currently plotting amplitude (V) vs. frequency (Hz).  I'd like to change the Y-Axis units to dB.  How would I go about doing this? What would be the units?

It is from my understanding that:

dB = 10log10(power/reference_power)

= 20log10(voltage/reference_voltage)

= 20log10(amplitude/reference_amplitude)     (units of amplitude is volts)

= 20log10(amplitude)                         (reference amplitude can be thought of as 1 Volt)

Is this the correct way to convert from amplitude to dB? Also, wouldn't this make the units be "dB (V)"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to convert from amplitude to dB? Also, wouldn't this make the units be "dB (V)"?

Yes, that's correct. Note that a reference voltage of 0.7746 is also used in the audio world and is denoted "dBu".

Some examples:

$$
\begin{align}
  \text{"in dBV"} &= 20\log\left(\frac{V_{in}}{1\text{V}}\right) \\
  \text{"in dBu"} &= 20\log\left(\frac{V_{in}}{0.775\text{V}}\right) \\
   \text{"in dBV"} - \text{"in dBu"} &= -20 \log \left(
            \frac{1}{0.775}
             \right) \\
     \text{"in dBV"} &= \text{"in dBu"} - 2.214 \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: ... and also denoted as dB**v**.

Comment: So you would divide a voltage in db by that \$dBv = 0.7746\$ and the result would essentially then be in per unit of the reference?

Comment: Aah ok this makes sense. Note that in my case, since my reference voltage is 1, the units would be denoted as dB**V**

Comment: 0.7746Vrms is 1 mW into the standard 600 ohm load so it's (at least nominally) referenced to 1 mW.